# IOS: why the first row of my tableview was blank?

Tags: ios

I defined some labels in my TableViewCell, and make my program read the information from a NSDictionary into the cells. but when I ran it, the first row of my tableview was blank, and the rest rows' display are normal. 
I tried to use NSLog to catch what were passed to the cell, and the answer was as the same as what is in the NSDictionary. 
where might the wrong be?

here is part of my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *TableSampleIdentifier = @"TableSampleIdentifier";

     TakeAwayCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: TableSampleIdentifier];

     if (!cell)
     {
         cell = [ [TakeAwayCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableSampleIdentifier];   //'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'error without this line

         UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TakeAwayCell" bundle:nil];
         [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:TableSampleIdentifier];
     }

     NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

     cell.image = self.list[row][@"image"];
     cell.name = self.list[row][@"name"];
     cell.addr = self.list[row][@"addr"];

     NSLog(@"%@",cell.name);

     return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check index of the `self.list`. It possibly starts from 1 not 0 in N`SUInteger row = [indexPath row];`

Answer (score 0):

Take this code of yours:

`UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TakeAwayCell" bundle:nil];
    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:TableSampleIdentifier];`

To your view did load and keep only the allocation on the cell creation delegate.

Comment: Not really. After doing what you suggested you can safely get rid of the `if (!cell)` allocation block because the returned cell will never be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

May be, it is because of the layout constraint. Make sure that the `tableview` align to the top of the screen.